# Доступ к одной записи в PDO

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных, pdo

Для перебора всех записей выборки используется код

```
$query=$mysqli_query($coonection, $sql);
$result = $query->execute();
while ($record=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
}
```

Какой аналог функции mysqli_fetch_assoc() есть в pdo?

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/pdostatement.fetch.php#refsect1-pdostatement.fetch-parameters

Comment: для доступа к одной записи цикл не нужен, нужно выбрать одну запись и сделать фетч. Если вы пишите про то чтобы перебрать все строки результата по одной, то в пдо есть fetchAll

Comment: @teran, а зачем fetchAll? Что pdo что mysqli давным давно `implements Traversable`. `foreach ($result as $row)` и всего делов

Comment: @Мелкий если логику и представление не отделять, а общие сведения о результатах, их группировка, кэширование и прочее не нужны, то в целом незачем,